# echo unmatched characters in regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to echo the unmatched characters in regex

```
$value = 'thisisthis123';
if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $value) )
{
    echo "CORRECT SYNTAX";
}
else
{
    echo "WRONG SYNTAX";
}
```

The above code works perfectly. But here comes the twist what if the syntax is wrong ? how can i echo the wrong characters

e.g.

```
$value = 'unwan@#-.';
if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $value) )
{
    echo "CORRECT SYNTAX";
}
else
{
    echo "WRONG SYNTAX";
}
```

Now i want to the echo to be like "WRONG SYNTAX" (@#-.)

Any idea how to accomplish this ? with preg or some other function ?

EDIT :

I want the matched characters and unmatched characters
e.g.

```
$matched = 'unwan';
$unmatched = '@#-.';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip all matched characters and so only the unmatched remain:

```
<?php
    $value = 'unwan@#-.';
    echo preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', '', $value) ;
?>
```

Output is `@#-.`

If you save the regex pattern in a variable, you don't have to type it twice (and update it twice if it changes). I also added your edit, you achieve this with a negated pattern (`^` in front of the pattern).

```
<?php
$value = 'unwan@#-.';
$pattern = 'a-zA-Z0-9 ';
if ( preg_match('/^['.$pattern.']+$/', $value) )
{
    echo "CORRECT SYNTAX";
}
else
{
    echo "WRONG SYNTAX".PHP_EOL;
    echo "matched: ".preg_replace('/[^'.$pattern.']/','',$value).PHP_EOL;
    echo "unmatched: ".preg_replace('/['.$pattern.']/','',$value).PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for those patterns which represent "CORRECT SYNTAX", look instead for those which represent "WRONG SYNTAX."  Then, capture those matches and print them out.

```
<?php

$value = 'unwan@#-.';
if ( preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/', $value, $matches) )
{
  echo "WRONG SYNTAX";
  foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo " ($match)";
  }
}
else
{
  echo "CORRECT SYNTAX";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw an answer has been accepted, but I provide this one, which does regexp only once and so costs less.
The predicate is:

- find a match;
- if that match has the same length as the value, it is a full match (syntax OK);
- else it is KO.

Since unmatched could occur at start AND at end, I put a placeholder `()` during replacement to separate wrong parts.

```
<?php
$value = 'unwan@#-';
$pattern = 'a-zA-Z0-9 ';
preg_match('/['.$pattern.']+/', $value, $matches) ;
if ( strlen($value) == strlen($matches[0]) )
{
    echo "CORRECT SYNTAX".PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
    echo "WRONG SYNTAX".PHP_EOL;
    echo "matched: ".$matches[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo "unmatched: ".str_replace($matches[0],'()',$value).PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```